# Is it possible to tap a word to select it in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am thinking of writing a translation app with jQuery mobile and wondering if it is somehow possible to tap a word in a sentence/paragraph/page/etc and then essentially 'get' that word to use elsewhere (for instance to add it to a list of words that need further study.

I also understand that in some devices (i.e. Android) a copy option might appear when tapping on a word - I'd like to disable this if possible as well. I've seen various ways to achieve this, however I just want to make it clear that I'm aware this is an issue that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, if that word is wrapped by some element:

```
<p>
   This is de <span class="doSomething" >word</span>
</p>
```

The javascript:

```
$(".doSomething").on("tap", ...
```

So, to achieve what you want, I would wrap every word with `span` tags

Comment: Hmm, i was hoping to pull long strings of text to display that I was hoping to allow to be tapped. As you say, I guess I could write some code to put a span around each word in the string. But is there another way to do it all in one go?

Comment: If you can edit the HTML, that is the easiest way. If you didn't disable the text selection, you could try to get the selected word, but I've been working with text selections and mobile devices and wouldn't recommend it, as it hard to find an universal solution to detect and get the selection for all the platforms